# Python Tkinter Name Error

Tags: python, tkinter

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
import sys
from tkinter import*

myGui=Tk()
nameentr=StringVar()

#myGui.geometry('450x450')
myGui.title('Playing with the layout of Buttons')

Label1=Label(myGui,text='Enter Text Here').pack()
textentry1=Entry(myGui,textvariable=nameentry).pack()

button1=Button(myGui,text='Button 1').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)
button2=Button(myGui,text='Button 2').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)
button3=Button(myGui,text='Button 3').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)
button4=Button(myGui,text='Button 4').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)
```

**HERE IS MY PROBLEM:**

```
textentry1=Entry(myGui,textvariable=nameentry).pack()
NameError: name 'nameentry' is not defined
```

Could someone please fix this error? Thanks

Comment: You should call `pack` on separate lines for all of your widgets. As in right now, _all_ of your widgets are anonymous and stored as `None`.  As further in `print(button1)` for example returns `>None`.

Comment: The first rule of debugging is to assume the error message is telling you something useful. In this case it definitely is.

Comment: I think this is a well-asked question. OP may be unable to debug their code by themselves from the error Traceback but they _did_ ask the question pretty good. I don't understand why someone would -1 this.

Comment: @Nae Probably for the same reason it has 4 close votes currently: this is a simple typo. Nobody but the asker is likely to ever find this question useful. (I didn't downvote, but I did close vote.)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define `nameentry` but `nameentr` in `nameentr=StringVar()` at `line 5`.